# Join signature with original file with JAVA

Tags: java, digital-signature

I need join signature data with original file using java.

```
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance(signatureAlgorithm, provider);
signer.initSign(key);
signer.update(input);
byte[] sign = signer.sign();
```

I have a png file (f) and I make it:

```
byte[] input = converterFileIntoByteArray(f);
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance(signatureAlgorithm, provider);
signer.initSign(key);
signer.update(input);
byte[] sign = signer.sign();
```

I do not want send to receiver two files (my png and your signature - the represents file from signature). I want join byte[] input and byte[] sign in a single file. But I need that file is still valid and can be read by programs. For exemple, if that file is a txt, so, this result file can be read by Note Pad, the same is valid to anothers files, as pdf, doc, jpeg.

Someone help me?

Comment: Certain file types allow embedding signatures, e.g. pdf, office formats, edi, xml, but each requires a specific implementation of the signing process. For others you might innovate some own embedding schemes. But there is no generic way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, in general, add extra data to a binary file and expect programs to just magically ignore the extra data.  Binary files (`.doc`, for instance) are expected to be in a specific format and contain data allowing programs to validate that they have not been corrupted.

This *may* be possible for some selected file formats but if you want to join a file and its signature you must put both inside some kind of container, like a `.zip` file.

The NTFS file system allows files to have more than one "data stream" and you could put the signature in an alternate stream, but this works only on Windows. There is no generally portable way to accomplish what you are asking for.